# Making separate app folder in the phone of the RN app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, whatsapp

I'm trying to make an app in **react native** that can create a folder and saves the relevant photos and videos categorized according to the tags in them. I have tried **react-native-fs' and 'react-native-fetch-blob'.** but they don't fit this purpose. I want to categorize the same way WhatsApp does.

Is there any way I could perform this function in react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get through this.

**Add the following line of code in androidManifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Now import these the following**

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
```

**NOW the function to make folder.**

```
const makefolder = async () => {
try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    {
      title: 'Permission',
      message: 'App needs to read storage ',
    },
  );
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    // get a list of files and directories in the main bundle
    RNFS.readDir(RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath)
      .then((result) => {
        let appFolder = 'checking123'; //folder name to create
        let path = RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath + '/' + appFolder;

        RNFS.mkdir(path).catch((error) => {
          console.log('failed to create folder');
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message, err.code);
      });
  } else {
    console.log('Permission Denied!');
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

};

Now you will be able to find the folder in the internal storage/android/{yourfoldername}/files

I found major help from [lylest](http://%20https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/677#issuecomment-633204198)